# Retrieving URL formed by CURL POST

Tags: php, curl

I want to retrieve the final URL formed using a `CURL` request, but none of them work what I want to retrieve.

for example - I directly paste an API call in the browser address bar, it works, but when using CURL request I get some errors.

To find that I want to retrieve the final request URL formed by CURL or all the request parameters included in CURL Request.

The various methods I have tried is like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
curl_close($ch);
```

Alternatively -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

Thanks.

Update:
My request should form url like this:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/?METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=86&PWD=9mypassword&USER=my_user_name&SIGNATURE=my_api_signature&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=FitnessMembership&cancelUrl=http://localhost/recurring-payment/index.php&returnUrl=http://localhost/recurring-payment/review.php
```

Now I want to get all the info in the above URL being submitted to Paypal API.

So I can retrieve this info being sent through CURL.

Comment: what are the "some errors?"

Comment: I am trying to send the request to paypal - I am getting the error response - invalid description. but I know I have included the correct description. Therefore I am looking what final URL is sent to PAYPAL

Comment: what happened when you var_dump the curl_getinfo($ch); I just tested it and it gave me the URL and some other header information. If an error is being thrown before it gets to that line then you should call that line earlier.

Comment: See here that it gives me an array of the request information http://ideone.com/W1NaHg . Oh looks like that site doesnt connect to DNS. but it showed  full results on my dev machine

Comment: What is the content of $url???

Comment: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com